# Defining a default in an OWL ontology

Tags: semantic-web, owl

I would like to define the existence of a default in an ontology. In practice, it would be like, after defining a data or object property with an associated default in the ontology, a reasoner would generate the tuple with the specified default value (if data property) or instance (if object property) if the tuple is not present.

I now know it is not possible to express this in OWL, but has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: No, OWL does not support default.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Ok. that's what I suspected, but I assume the problem is rather common, so someone must have come up with a workaround.

Comment: @Stefano This is not a problem, this is a specific feature of OWL know as the Open World Assumption. In short : an entity may have a value but still don't know what is the value, that do not mean that the entity don't have the value. example : You know that a plan will be available for you fly, but you don't know what plane; While specific plane existe. If you don't like Open World Assumption (OWA) you should considere using langage like Prolog.

Comment: @Galigator I can't go with prolog. I need to express a taxonomy of entities, each entity having some properties, and if one property is not specified then its value is the default. How would you do that in a reasonable format?

Comment: @Stefano I understand.So you may considere KM : http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mfkb/RKF/km.html it is also OWA, but do not check _consistency_ before reasoning. By using the 'frame' you can define 'class' with something that maybe a default (and overload). Without _consistency_ you may experiment logical failure days after inserting an error/conflicting statement.

Comment: Maybe I should better clarify my intent. I don't need to do any logical reasoning. I am trying to describe a data model, the constraints of this data model, and the relationships between entities in it, and I have to do it in a form that allows me to describe the taxonomy of these entities, possibly using a decent tool (akin to protege')

Comment: Please provide some ontology that you are currently working with, and also briefly explain how you want the defaults be used, and then maybe someone can help you.